# Given $u∈\mathbb{R}^n$, show that $W_u:=\{v∈\mathbb{R}^n\mid u \cdot v=0\}$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V= \mathbb{R}^n $ and $u\in V$. Denote
>
> $$W_u:=\{v\in V\mid u\cdot v=0\}.$$
>
> Show that $W_u$ is a subspace of $V$.

The 3 things that need to be true are

1. $W_u$ has the element $0$ in it.
2. It's closed under addition
3. It's closed under scalar multiplication

For 1, $u\in V$ and $v\in V$ therefore, $W_u = 0 \cdot 0=0$ has the element $0$ in it.
Is this the correct way to prove that the element $0$ is in $W_u$?

How do you prove that its closed under addition and multiplication?

Comment: What does the star operation represent?

Comment: basically,take two elements from $W_u$, say $u,v$ and then show that $u+v \in W_u$

Comment: @Winston multiplication

Comment: @Charlene: Do you mean dot product? You can't multiply vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (unless $n = 1$).

Comment: @Charlene, refer to michael's comment

Comment: I think it should be inner product

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes you're correct, dot product.

Comment: Use one step test to finish your ans.

Comment: @Charlene in your proof you are assuming that u is specifically the zero vector...something more general needs to be and can be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the zero vector $0$. It satisfies that $0\cdot u=0.$ So $0\in W_u$.

Consider two vectors $a,b\in W_u$. By definition, we know that $au=0$ and $bu=0$. Consider $a+b$. $(a+b)u=au+bu=0+0=0.$

Consider a vector $v\in W_u$. By definition, $vu=0$. For any scalar $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $(av)u=a(vu)=a0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$W_u$ is the kernel of the linear form $\;v\longmapsto u\cdot v$.

Answer (score 1):

This is strightforward checking: if $a, b\in W_u$, i.e.
$$
u\cdot a = 0, u\cdot b = 0,
$$
then
$$
u\cdot a + u\cdot b = u\cdot (a+b) = 0.
$$
And for 3):
$$
\alpha (u\cdot a) = 0\Longrightarrow u\cdot(\alpha a)=0.
$$
So, both $a+b$ and $\alpha a$ are in $W_u$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $u \cdot (v' + v'') = u \cdot v' + u\cdot v''$